# How to set default magnification for all windows

Tags: notebooks

This is certainly a newbie question but I could not find the answer by searching.

I am using Mathematica 8 under Windows 7. I want to use default magnification of 150% for all notebooks and help files which I open in Mathematica. At present I have to do it through Windows->Magnification for every single document I open which is of course tedious. I assume there is a way of setting some options which is saved across different sessions as well.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Related: [Fontsize is too small](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/745/121)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If the reason you ask is because the fonts are much too small, then there is another approach that is arguably more correct than changing Magnification, and that is to specify a better screen resolution.  By default it is 72ppi, but screens haven't been like that for years (mine is about 100ppi).

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, 
 FontProperties -> {"ScreenResolution" -> 96}
]
```

If you like the setting and what to make it persist between sessions, replace `$FrontEndSession` with `$FrontEnd`.

Comment: You can also set this to `Automatic`, or alternatively set it from the options inspector. I'd love to know what it actually does, though... I set mine to 72 and to 135 to see the difference, and nothing seemed to happen.

Comment: @acl on Windows 7 it makes a *huge* difference; the fonts scale proportionately.  It would be worth a new question why this doesn't work on your system.

Comment: I am not sure it doesn't: Heike pointed this out some time ago (in some other answer), and I recall it did make a difference. I'll try to work out what is going on.

Comment: @acl perhaps my `SetOptions` form is not system-independent?

Comment: It appears to be: it sets the same thing as the options inspector. I am trying to work out what is going on (have been working until now and did not get a chance to).

Comment: @Spartacus thanks for the suggestion. As you said it does make a huge difference in Windows 7.

Comment: The disadvantage is that images won't be shown pixel-to-pixel when at 100% magnification.  I.e. while the solution you describe should be smarter than a simple magnification change, unfortunately it is not.  I wish I could find a solution which leaves `Image`s alone.

Comment: @Szabolcs are you referring to the font size in graphics?  Either `"ScreenResolution"` or BaseStyle (what I actually use most of the time because I am too lazy to change hard-coded font sizes in old Notebooks) will result in larger-than-default text, but IMHO this is a good thing as the default is too small.  Magnification can be a good option, but it takes a lot for small text like Messages to be easily readable, and using it *all pixel dimensions are wrong*, including raster images (unless specifically resized).

Comment: On the other hand using `"ScreenResolution"` can result in text in the GUI being cut off.  There is no perfect solution I am aware of other than updating basic *Mathematica* properties for modern displays.

Comment: No, I am referring to `Image`s, not vector `Graphics`.  I'd expect images to be displayed one image pixel to one screen pixel regardless of the DPI setting.  The only reason I didn't increase the DPI setting is this (and perhaps that it also affects palettes---but that is expected and correct behaviour)

Comment: @Szabolcs I am not seeing that behavior.  I'll take a look at this later today; I just stopped by for a few minutes now.

Comment: This also distorts GUI elements like palletes at least on Linux.

Answer (score 32):

Here are step by step instructions:

1. Open the menu item `Format -> Options Inspector...`
2. Set "Show option values" to "Global Preferences"
3. Find `Notebook Options -> Display Options`
4. Set Magnification to 1.5

Now all your notebooks will show at 150% magnification.

Comment: Many thanks, works like a charm.

Comment: @Szabolcs When I do the above procedure, it affects magnification on all existing notebooks, but new notebooks still open at 100%, not at 1.25 (which is what I set this option to). Am I missing something?

Comment: @rogerl Does it show 100% in the status bar or is it actually 100%?  It seems it does show 100%, but the base magnification is actually higher, even in newly opened notebooks. (As you can see from the text size.)

Comment: @Szabolcs Yeah, the base magnification is higher. A little odd and confusing. Thanks.

Comment: Note: If your Notebook (or maybe cell, graphics, plot) defines `ScreenResolution`, this will override the Global Preference, so you will see no effect. See my answer.

Comment: @NoEscape Thanks for the idea.  The reason I wouldn't use this is that it'd have an effect for that notebook on all computers, while the main reason for setting a high dpi is  high resolution (tiny text) screen

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been trying to fix this for hours and this worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

The better option may be setting `"ScreenResolution"` on a per notebook basis.
This way you do not change the appearance of the palettes, help browser, etc.

Try

```
SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
 FontProperties -> {"ScreenResolution" -> Automatic}
]
```

instead of `Automatic` you can put in a number. Try moving from 72 upward. 96 is a good value for todays systems/screens. Automatic results in 96 on my system. If the Times font is still too small for you, try 108 or more.

Of course you can set the corresponding value via the Option Inspector (Formatting Options - Font Options - FontProperties - ScreenResolution). Just remember choosing "Selected Notebook" in the first listbox.

Comment: Note: Magnification can be safely set on a global base. See Szabolcs' post. If you want to enlarge ALL Palettes and the Help Browser, set global Magnification first, then adjust your ScreenResolution per notebook!

Comment: I tried SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
 FontProperties -> {"ScreenResolution" -> Automatic}
] and it made no difference to the font size, what is wrong?