# How do I change my font size to 18 points globally?

Tags: fonts

The default font is WAY too small.  I can't read it on my jumbo-size laptop monitor, and my professors can't read my papers when I turn them in.

Can somebody please provide DETAILED instructions on how to change the GLOBAL default font size to 18 points?

Comment: Have you tried changing the Magnification? _Window -> Magnification -> x %_

Comment: I don't recall asking about magnification.  I want to change the global font, not just the appearance on my screen.  I think I may have found something in another comment "SetOptions[$FrontEnd, FontSize -> 16]"

Comment: Well, magnification is the easiest way to make things look bigger, so I asked.

Comment: Answer found here:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1981/keeping-text-size-the-same-throughout-entire-notebook-file

Comment: Thanks for the link, your question will now be closed a duplicate :)

Answer (score 6):

I use *Format/Option Inspector/Formatting Options/Font Options*
then look through and change as much as you like including font options:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

EDIT actually as mentioned the link found here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1981/keeping-text-size-the-same-throughout-entire-notebook-file

is much more efficient.