# Make Rasterize/Export use Notebook-specific options?

Tags: front-end, export, notebooks, options, style

Sometimes I need Notebook-specific options such as [`Background`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Background.html) color or `FontProperties -> "ScreenResolution"`.  (Ref: [How to set default magnification for all windows](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1310/121).)

This works just fine in most ways, except that when I use any of:

- [`Rasterize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rasterize.html)
- [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html)
- [**Save Selection As...**](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/SaveSelectionAs.html)

the **Global** value is used rather than the **Notebook** value, and the image is very different.

Here is a self-contained example:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession,
  {Background -> None, 
   FontProperties -> {"ScreenResolution" -> 96}}];

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[],
  {Background -> LightBlue, 
   FontProperties -> {"ScreenResolution" -> 72}}];

Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10},
 Epilog -> Text[Style[Sinc[x], 16], {5.5, 1/2}], 
 ImageSize -> Small
]

Rasterize[%]
```

[image]

Is there some way to make these export methods use the **Notebook** options?

(I am especially concerned with the `FontProperties -> "ScreenResolution"` value.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following approach seems to work:

```
SetOptions[$FrontEndSession, {Background -> None, 
   FontProperties -> {"ScreenResolution" -> 96}}];

SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], {Background -> LightBlue, 
   FontProperties -> {"ScreenResolution" -> 72}}];

pl = Plot[Sinc[x], {x, 0, 10}, Epilog -> Text[Style[Sinc[x], 16], {5.5, 1/2}], 
  ImageSize -> Small]

Rasterize[Style[pl, Options[EvaluationNotebook[]]]]
```

[image: screenshot]

It is possible to achieve better quality by specifying higher `ImageResolution`:

```
Rasterize[Style[pl, Options[EvaluationNotebook[]]], ImageResolution -> 200]
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I thought I tried `"ScreenResolution"` in `Style` and it didn't work which is why I emphasized that aspect.  However I am thrilled to learn that it does!  Thank you!  I'll test this a bit further and wait 24 hours as I have made customary before accepting, but it seems to be the solution I needed.