# Change size of front-end windows and palette default (in Windows 7)

Tags: front-end

I need to open a notebook to appear by default to 150% as well as the symbol palettes to 150%, I looked like but I can not find it.
Help me please
[image]

Comment: Possibly useful (I hope; it's my self Q&A): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72989/121

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1310/121

Comment: lookme 
Here are step by step instructions:
 Open the menu item Format -> Options Inspector...

    Set "Show option values" to "Global Preferences"

    Find Notebook Options -> Display Options
 
   **Set Magnification to 1.5

Now all your notebooks will show at 150% magnification.**

_It does not work , I also do not see where to change the size of the palette_

Comment: lilo so would you consider this question a duplicate?  If so I shall mark it as one.

Comment: If in part, but two questions in one

Answer (score 1):

`CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, Magnification] = 1.5` should do it.