# How to change default settings of cell formatting?

Tags: formatting

I find font size of Text cells too small and I like displaying them with background colour... I've read this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/745/fontsize-is-too-small?rq=1) and learned about `Menu/Format/Option Inspector...` where I managed to change font size, but it affects all cells.

I would like to change separately Text, Input and Output formatting and to save these settings as default for displaying any notebooks. So, when I next time select a cell, then go to `Menu/Format/Style` and choose Text or Input or Output; it applies **my** default formatting for Text, Input, Output or anything else.

Is this supported with `Option Inspector` or some other tool?

Comment: Default settings for font sizes and appearance in cells are due to the default stylesheet. If you want to depart from default settings *regularly*, without manually setting these parameters with the options inspector, then you will have to make a new stylesheet and use that with your notebooks. There are many stylesheet related answers here that cover how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I did not like small font size in Notebook and solved this by the following:

Open "Option Inspector"
Search for "DefaultNewCellStyle" option in "Global Preferences"
Set it to something like "{"Input", FontFamily -> "Ubuntu Mono", FontSize -> 16}"
(Change fontFamily to a font you do have installed)

Now enjoying lager font by default in Input cells. Hope this will somehow help you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

In the `Option Inspector` Choose from:

[image]

Then configure your settings.

[image]

Setting them globally sounds like want you want.

You can also use and modify various `Stylesheets`.  Access then from the `Format` menu