# How to fold output cells by default?

Tags: front-end, cells

In *Mathematica* the default behavior of output cells is to pop up after the kernel has processed the input cells and got a result. I know I could add `;` in the end of input cells to disable output cells, which are often too messy in the middle of my calculations and usually I don't really care what they are, from appearing. However sometimes I need to go back and check some stuff, so it is still necessary to keep those intermediate results there. Then my questions is that **is it possible to "fold" output cells?** By "folding" I mean it would look as if I manually double click the cell, so the output cell will be hidden and an arrow appears next to the input cell. I tried to find some related settings described in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20893/how-to-change-default-settings-of-cell-formatting), but nothing useful there. Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry @Nasser, I don't get it either...It seems like you're talking about putting a series of steps in a single function (using `Module` or something similar), which I already know (and I choose not to do for some reasons).

Comment: By the way, the jumping cursor you're talking about could be achieved (though taking one more step) by pressing ↓ after evaluating a cell and then pressing shift+enter. Is it what you want?

Comment: yeah mathematica is inefficient in this indeed...

Comment: This is nearly a duplicate of [(3235)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3235/121) but that doesn't address folding all output automatically without using the special function.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard you are always our wizard! It would be great if it could be done automatically without any special function, but I'm almost satisfied with `AutoCollapse` since it seems unlikely to have something fancier.

Comment: sorry actually I was talking about `autoFoldOutput`...

Comment: I believe I have your solution.  Please see the answer below. :-)

Comment: @Nasser I believe your "extra step" problem may also be solved with `CellEpilog`.  Would you care to post a question regarding that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm slow, but eventually I get there. ;-)  You need [`CellEpilog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellEpilog.html) to make the behavior automatic on evaluation of any cell.  Importing the code from my [`autoFoldOutput`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3260/121) function:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 CellEpilog :> 
   (SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], All, EvaluationCell];
    FrontEndTokenExecute["SelectionCloseUnselectedCells"])
]
```

Simply evaluate that in your Notebook and all output groups will be automatically closed when they are created.  You may replace `EvaluationNotebook[]` with `$FrontEndSession` if you want to affect all Notebooks during the session or with `$FrontEnd` to persistently affect all Notebooks.

Comment: This is awesome Mr. Wizard! One quick question: Will the effect of using `$FrontEnd` continue even the kernel is closed and then reactivated?

Comment: @Leo I'm glad you like it. :-)  Yes, settings to `$FrontEnd` should persist between sessions; this is the same as setting them in the **Global Preferences** item of the **Option Inspector** (but don't try setting this complicated definition from there).  They can be viewed and cleared from there as well (**as text** will show everything), so you don't have to worry about not being able to restore default behavior.

Comment: Good to know! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but the `Cell` menu has an item that collapses open cells:

[image: menu]

Here I highlighted the open input/output cells and then collapsed them to get the following:

[image: collapsed]

If your question is about *automatically* and immediately collapsing every output cell, then that's a different story. It will most likely involve [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/683/245).

Comment: Thanks Jens! I think Mr. Wizard's `AutoCollapse` could provide the effect I expect! It seems that when an output cell is generated, the selection is moved to the input cell by `AutoCollapse`, leaving the output cell unselected and then closing it by `SelectionCloseUnselectedCells`, which is effectively the same as the `Close Unselected Cells` button in your screenshot. I just wonder how do I rewrite `AutoCollapse` to make it do the opposite way, because I didn't see any token providing the effect of SelectionClose"Selected"Cells.

Comment: Aha! Mr. Wizard has provided another post which has the desired function.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two other alternatives:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], 
 "GeneratedCellStyles" -> {"Output" -> {"Output", CellOpen -> False}}]
```

And:

```
Dynamic[
 SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], CellOpen -> False];
 myHiddenContent
 ]
```

You could even make a one-shot, so that the cell initially displays unopened, but the user has the option to manually open it, without `Dynamic` getting in the way:

```
Evaluate[closeIt = True];
Dynamic[
 If[closeIt,
  SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], CellOpen -> False];
  closeIt = False
  ];
 myHiddenContent
 ]
```

(A more complete solution would use `DynamicModule` too)

The first solution prevents any "flashing" of an output cell that is temporarily shown before then being hidden.  If you put the `SetOptions` piece of code as the first line in `Dynamic` in the second solution, in practice, I don't notice any flashing.  Using other methods that don't close the cell until *after* it has been shown *with content in it* might result in flashing of temporary contents on the screen.