# Is it possible to limit maximum number of characters on a line in Notebook?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, formatting, cells

I would like to be able to set a limit on the maximum number of characters on every line in notebook (for example, 80). Does *Mathematica* provide this functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [`PageWidth`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PageWidth.html):

> `PageWidth` is an option for output streams and for cells which
>   specifies how wide each line of text should be allowed to be.
>
> Possible settings for cells are:
>
> - `WindowWidth`  the width of the window on the screen
> - `PaperWidth`   the width of the page as it would be printed
> - `n`    explicit width given in printer's points

We [can](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionsForNotebooks.html#4734) set this option at the Notebook level (with lower priority than at the level of individual cell):

> The Wolfram Language allows you to take any cell option and set it at the notebook level, thereby specifying a global default for that option throughout the notebook.

We have to take into account that `PageWidth` includes the following values:

1. [`CellMargins`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellMargins.html)
2. [`CellFrameMargins`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellFrameMargins.html) with the space occupied by [`CellFrame`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellFrame.html) (if `CellFrame` is turned on)
3. The space occupied by [`CellLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellLabel.html) (if is turned on and shown on the left, what is controlled by [`ShowCellLabel`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ShowCellLabel.html) and [`CellLabelPositioning`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellLabelPositioning.html)); `CellLabelMargins` seems to be ignored by now.
4. [`CellFrameLabelMargins`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellFrameLabelMargins.html) with the space occupied by [`CellFrameLabels`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellFrameLabels.html) themselves (if the latter are turned on)

[Update: 5. `"Widths"` suboption of [`CellBracketOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellBracketOptions.html). I didn't try to figured out how it interferes with the above options.]

From the above list only calculation of the space occupied by `CellLabel` and `CellFrameLabels` isn't straightforward since it isn't known beforehand how much space do they need. Fortunately, by default there are no `CellFrameLabels`, and `CellLabel` also doesn't take any additional space [because](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellLabelPositioning.html)

> With the default setting `CellLabelPositioning -> Automatic`, the label for a cell is placed to the left of the cell if it is short enough to fit in the left margin. Otherwise, the label is placed above the cell.

Hence with the default settings it is sufficient to take into account only `CellMargins`, `CellFrame` and `CellFrameMargins`. Here is [how](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/147243/280) one can find their portion inside of `PageWidth`:

```
margins = Total[Replace[
   Switch[CurrentValue[{CellFrame, 1}],
    True | {True, True}, {CurrentValue[{CellMargins, 1}], CurrentValue[{CellFrameMargins, 1}]},
    _?NumericQ | {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, {CurrentValue[{CellMargins, 1}], CurrentValue[{CellFrameMargins, 1}]*Sign[Abs[CurrentValue[{CellFrame, 1}]]], CurrentValue[{CellFrame, 1}]},
    _, {CurrentValue[{CellMargins, 1}]}], {x_?NumericQ :> 2 x, l_List :> Total[l]}, {1}]]
```

> ```
> 76
> ```

(the above implementation doesn't handle correctly mixed specifications for `CellFrame`; complete implementation can be found in [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147281/280) answer.)

Knowing `margins`, we can restrict cell contents to be 400 pts wide:

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], PageWidth -> 400 + margins]
```

And here is a way to make this option `Dynamic` (the implementation is very basic: it assumes that `CellFrame` may be only either `True` or `False`):

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], PageWidth -> Dynamic[400 +
  Total[Replace[
    If[TrueQ@CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {StyleDefinitions, "Input", CellFrame}],
     {CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {StyleDefinitions, "Input", CellFrameMargins}],
      CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {StyleDefinitions, "Input", CellMargins}]},
     {CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {StyleDefinitions, "Input", CellMargins}]}], 
     {x_?NumberQ :> 2 x, l_List :> Total[First[l]]}, {1}]]]]
```

---

`PageWidth` allows to specify the maximum width in *printer's points* (what for the purposes of on-screen display we [may read as *pixels*](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109838/280)). If you use a mono-spaced font like Courier, it shouldn't be too difficult to establish the correspondence between the number of characters and the width of the line.

Here is a quick check up for all printable ASCII and Greek characters:

```
With[{chrs = 
   Join[CharacterRange[" ", "~"], 
    CharacterRange["\[CapitalAlpha]", "\[Omega]"]]},
 Table[Rasterize[StringJoin@Take[chrs, n], "RasterSize"][[1]]/n // N,
  {n, 1, Length[chrs]}]]
```

> `{7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.02273,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.01818,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.01563,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.01282,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.00709,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.00685,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.,7.}`

We see that for Courier (my default font) with default `FontSize -> 12` the width of a character is equal to 7 *pixels*. Small inconsistency comes from the fact that `Rasterize[string, "RasterSize"]` isn't precise for strings.