# Correct arithmetics for CellMargins, CellFrame and CellFrameMargins

Tags: front-end, programming, dynamic, notebooks, options

When writing [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/147217/280) answer I came into trouble trying to calculate total horizontal margins for contents of a cell in the right way. The first part of the problem is that both `CellMargins` and `CellFrameMargins` can be explicitly specified in [two ways](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/CellMargins.html):

> Possible settings are:
>
> 1. `dist`    the same margins on all sides
> 2. `{{left,right},{bottom,top}}` different margins on different sides

With the first specification I have to double the value of the option, with the second I have to take the first element of the list and then sum up the values. Of course I can write a function which will handle both situations separately, but may be there is an elegant way to avoid this?

The second part of the problem is that the value of `CellFrameMargins` is used *only* if the corresponding value of `CellFrame` is `True` or a numeric nonzero. And all the numeric values are allowed to be negative. Here is a simple setup for playing with these options:

```
cell = Notebook[{Cell[StringJoin[Table["abcd ", {20}]]]}, 
   PageWidth -> 600,  
   CellMargins -> {{200, 200}, {10, 10}}, 
   CellFrame -> {{True, True}, {True, True}},
   CellFrameMargins -> {{20, 20}, {10, 10}}];
Rasterize[cell, "Image"]
% // ImageDimensions
```

> [image]
>
> ```
> {200, 84}
> ```

Currently the best I come up with is the following:

```
margins = Total[Replace[
   Switch[CurrentValue[{CellFrame, 1}],
    True | {True, True}, {CurrentValue[{CellMargins, 1}], CurrentValue[{CellFrameMargins, 1}]},
    _?NumericQ | {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}, {CurrentValue[{CellMargins, 1}], CurrentValue[{CellFrameMargins, 1}]*Sign[Abs[CurrentValue[{CellFrame, 1}]]], CurrentValue[{CellFrame, 1}]},
    _, {CurrentValue[{CellMargins, 1}]}], {x_?NumericQ :> 2 x, l_List :> Total[l]}, {1}]]
```

This solution is already ugly and complicated but still doesn't handle correctly mixed specifications like `CellFrame -> {{1, True}, {1, 1}}`. And my final intention is to use it in `Dynamic` where the above simple forms of `CurrentValue` should be replaced with `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {StyleDefinitions, "Input", CellFrame}]` etc.

Is there a better way to get the complete margins?

Answer (score 1):

It seems the best way is to lead to the canonical form `{{_, _}, {_, _}}` every option on the first step, then handle their inter-dependencies separately. The following module returns complete horizontal and vertical margins `{mHor, mVert}` for `"Input"` style:

```
Module[{m, f, fm},
 {m, f, fm} = CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {StyleDefinitions, "Input", #}] & /@ {CellMargins, CellFrame, CellFrameMargins};
 (* canonicalization *)
 {m, f, fm} = Replace[{m, f, fm}, x : Except[{{_, _}, {_, _}}] :> {{x, x}, {x, x}}, {1}];
 (* replacing CellFrameMargins by zeros where the frame is off *)
 fm = ReplacePart[fm, Position[f, Except[True | _?(Positive[Abs[#]] &)], {2}, Heads -> False] -> 0];
 (* clearing up non-numeric values *)
 {m, f, fm} = Replace[{m, f, fm}, x_ /; Not@NumericQ[x] :> 0, {3}];
 Total /@ (m + f + fm)]
```

> ```
> {76, 15}
> ```

Note that the above implementation is still incomplete because it doesn't take into account `CellLabelMargins` and `CellFrameLabelMargins` as well as `"Widths"` suboption of [`CellBracketOptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellBracketOptions.html).