# How to measure distance exactly from a graph?

Tags: plotting, graphics, distance

Is there any way to measure a distance from a graph in centimeter or inch exactly in *Mathematica*? I tried to use toolbar Ruler but I can only use it to measure width horizontally and can't switch it vertically to measure height. Also, I don't think we can use it to measure exactly the anything.

To be more specific, I am trying to measure the coordinates returns by function `Offset[{10, 20}, {0, 0}]` as bellow and check whether the offset distance is `{10/72,20/72) inch` or not.

```
Graphics[Rectangle[Offset[{10, 20}, {0, 0}], Offset[{-10, -20}, {1, 1}]], Frame -> True]
```

So how can I measure these distances? The purpose of the measurement is to check if I understand the offset coordinate correctly.

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109813/280

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
g = Graphics[
  Annotation[
   Rectangle[Offset[{10, 20}, {0, 0}], Offset[{-10, -20}, {1, 1}]], 
   "Rectangle", "Region"], ImageSize -> 100, PlotRangePadding -> None];

Rasterize[g, "Regions"]
```

> ```
> {{"Rectangle", "Region"} -> {{10., 20.}, {89., 79.}}}
> ```

Recommended reading:

- [What is a printer's point?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109813/280)

Comment: What is the unit of `"Region"`? How to display it in inch or cm?

Comment: @anhna It is pixels on the final rendered image. See the linked question about how they are connected to printer's points and inches.