# Is there a way to get the exact measurements on the screen in mathematica?

Tags: front-end

Suppose I want to make a rectangle that is 50mm x 70mm and I want to inscribe a ellipse with x radius 10mm and y radius 15.5mm centered at 20mm from top and in the middle across.

I can get the dimensionless picture that is proportionally correct as follows:

```
Graphics[{
    {Black,Rectangle[{0,0},{50,70}]},
    {Gray,Disk[{25,70-20},{20/2,31/2}]}
}]
```

Is there a way to get the exact dimensions printed on the screen? So if I place an actually object of such dimensions on the screen it overlap completely?

Wolfram language does have a notion of measures of length like millimeter `Quantity["Millimeters"]` but can it print it exactly on the screen so I can make comparisons?

Comment: Lots of good info on the topic here (and elsewhere): https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109813/what-is-a-printers-point

Comment: @user6014 I can't get it to work, if you can just show for this simple example that would be helpful.