# What is the unit for WindowSize

Tags: notebooks, size

On my computer, `First[WindowSize/.Options[EvaluationNotebook[]]]` gives me 1432.5 if the notebook has maximum width for my screen.

My screen resolution is 1920*1080 however. So the result can't be in pixels.

**What's the unit returned by `WindowSize`?**

Another strange observation: I can make the window narrower, e.g.

`SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], WindowSize -> {716, 760.5}]`. If I look at WindowsSize programmatically I get

`WindowSize /. Options[EvaluationNotebook[]]`

`{716.25,760.5}`

**What causes the extra 0.25 whatever-units width?**

Comment: Please take a look: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/109813/5478

Answer (score 5):

They are in Points, as documented [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WindowSize.html).

Comment: Is one point=1/72 inch = 127/360 mm? Does it depend on dpi settings in the operating system (in my case: Xubuntu 20.04). Fortunately the returned value does not depend on the Magnification set for Mma! (I have not tried to alter the operating system's dpi settings: they are shown to be 96 dpi, but if I divide the screen pixel dimensions by the sizes in inches I get ca 142 dpi if I compute it with the results from `xrandr | grep -w connected`).

Comment: It depends on the logical resolution of the display.  i.e., what the OS reports, not the physical device. If you set the display to be 200% in your OS's display settings app, it should report 192.   You can find this (along with other display characteristics) using `SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"]`.