# Wrong characters when exporting a plot as pdf

Tags: export, pdf-format, fonts

When I export a Plot in Mathematica as a PDF characters in PlotLegends and AxesLabels get replaced by other characters.

My code:

```
plot = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> {"T = 1"}, AxesLabel -> {"p / GeV", "M in GeV^-1 "}]

Export["/home/test.pdf", plot, "PDF"]

Export["/home/test2.png", plot, "PNG"]
```

This code gives me wrong characters in the pdf file, and right ones in the png file (the "=", "-", "/" are wrong).
[image: The Plot when I export it as a pdf. Note: I can not place pdf here, so I used an online pdf to png converter here]

[image: The Plot when I export it as a png.]

VersionNumber: 13.1 on Linux

Comment: hint: whenever you report a problem always indicate the version number and the OS you are using.   I just tried the above on V 13.2 on windows 10. No problems at all.

Comment: Tested in `13.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)` Wolfram Engine, and I see no problems here.

Comment: Could you try specifying the fonts explicitly?  Look at [23471](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23471/10397).

Comment: Please read the guidelines for the [tag:bugs] tag.