# How to increase font size in front-end UI Menus

Tags: front-end

Is it possible to increase the font size in the notebook GUI's menus, messages window, help windows, etc?

Comment: Do you want to increase the size in MMA only, or would a system wide change work as well? What version? What OS?

Comment: Maybe you could take a look at this question too: [Font size is too small](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/745/fontsize-is-too-small), although I'm not sure that it will address your problem in full.

Comment: Help windows are notebooks, different from the menus you mention. So the answer to @MarcoB s question is quite important for a useful answer.

Comment: When working from RDP via different machines, the message window in Mathematica 11.3 will getting blurry and cannot show full size. A get around method is to show kernel message to notebook as well: change the Global Options->MessageOptions->KernelMessageAction to add PrintToNoteBook